# Is there a way to put NLog.config information inside of my app.config file?

Tags: .net, app-config, nlog, nlog-configuration

Is there a way to put NLog.config information inside of my app.config file?  This way I can have one config file instead of two.  It could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="..." />
  </configSections>
  <nlog>
    <targets>...</targets>
    <rules>...</rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

Please let me know if this is a duplicate.

Comment: It is right in the documentation: `<section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>` https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#configuration-file-locations

Comment: @nemesv, that's exactly what I wanted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Of course that you can put the configuration in your app.config file.

You just need to use the `NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler` so you need to write

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
  </configSections>
  <nlog>
    <targets>...</targets>
    <rules>...</rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

as described  in the [NLog documentation](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki) in the [Configuration file format](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#configuration-file-format) section.